# Toad Error when trying to debug a package with XMLTYPE as a parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, access-violation, toad, xmltype

When I try to debug a package, which has XMLTYPE as a input data i get a access violation error.

```
Access violation at address 00409664 in module 'Toad.exe'. Read of address 0000901B
```

The versions are listed below:

Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0
Oracle Client : 11.2.0.1.0
Toad          : 11.6.1.6

The package I created is given below:

```
/**************************************************/

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SA.Cust_Orders AS
    PROCEDURE save_order
        (p_data             IN  XMLTYPE
        , p_return_code     OUT NUMBER
        , p_status_msg      OUT VARCHAR2);
    END Cust_Orders;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SA.Cust_Orders AS
    PROCEDURE save_order
        (p_data             IN  XMLTYPE
        , p_return_code     OUT NUMBER
        , p_status_msg      OUT VARCHAR2) IS
        BEGIN
            p_return_code := 0;
            p_status_msg := 'Data has been successfully saved.';
        END save_order;
    END Cust_Orders;

/**************************************************/
```

If I remove the "p_data" from the parameters I am able to debug.

Comment: http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10/t/22935

Comment: @ruudvan post is for working with XMLTYPE data. This is somewhat different and may still be problematic in some cases. Here is a more appropriate thread, but we weren't able to get to the bottom of it. http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10/t/26830 For me it's working OK in both 11.6 and 12.8 when passing in NULL or an XML document. Toad will cast your XML text typed into the Set Params dialog as XMLTYPE(). Are you modifying the anonymous block that Toad generates to kick off debugging? If so, how? What is your input value for p_data?

Comment: I was testing 11.2.0.1 fat client against 11.2.0.2 XE instance.

Comment: @MichaelS., You're right. I actually just tried it in 12.8.0.49 and I can reproduce this issue. I could've sworn that this worked fine for me because I work with XMLs all day, but apparently doesn't. My test was with a simple procedure that does nothing. `create procedure x (p in xmltype) as BEGIN NULL; END;`

Comment: I would say opening a service request with toad support would be your best bet.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure what the difference is, but your sample @ruudvan compiles fine for me and executes fine using the debugger. I didn't set any breakpoints or set an input parameter value for p.

Comment: Yeah, Dell Support would be a good bet. You can also save everyone a lot of time and make a Toad World account and post there the main Toad for Oracle forum. We might still punt you to support, but if you go to support first it's gonna get back to development eventually, but posting to Toad World will reach us immediately. :-) I'll still have the same questions for you there that I had above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be only answered by developers of a commercial product having access to the source code.